# My script fails to source the title of a food store from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script in python to scrape only the name of a food store from a webpage. However, when I execute my script I get the following error.

```
name = soup.select_one("h1.listing-name").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

[Address to that site](https://www.yellowpages.com.au/sa/gawler/mega-health-gawler-14366108-listing.html)

My attempt so far with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com.au/sa/gawler/mega-health-gawler-14366108-listing.html"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0"
    response = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    name = soup.select_one("h1.listing-name").text
    print(name)
```

The content I'm after is not generated dynamically. Moreover, the selector I've used within my script is flawless. How can I print the name of that store from that site?

Comment: The first thing I got when I opened that link was a captcha page. Are you sure, your script is getting the same page as you are seeing in the browser? I suggest trying on a static, locally hosted, copy of that page

Comment: it looks like your script is doing what's expected, it prints "Mega Health Gawler", i just tested it and it works, am I missing something?

Comment: For other answerers trying to get the MCVE running : `conda create -n temp python=3 beautifulsoup4 requests lxml` if you already have conda installed. I could reproduce the issue

Comment: You would need a proxy or VPN to get around that ip address block

Comment: @pguardiario perhaps. But I doubt the IP is the only metric they are using. Possibly adding a session cookie could be enough

Comment: @lucidbrot - I do yellowpages.com.au all the time, believe it or not. It's just the ip address.

Comment: @pguardiario solving the captcha in rhe browser does not unlock access for the script from the same IP though. At least not for me

Comment: I'm saying as long as you haven't hit them lately from that ip address and you send good headers you won't get a captcha. That user-agent for example looks suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your script to see what it gets from the server:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import requests

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com.au/sa/gawler/mega-health-gawler-14366108-listing.html"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
    response = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    if soup is not None:
        selected = soup.select_one("h1.listing-name")
        if selected is not None:
            name = soup.selected.text
            print(name)
        else:
            print("Oh No!\n{}".format(soup))
    else:
        print("Ooops!\n{}".format(response))
```

and then I've run it. The result is the captcha page below. You need to figure out how to get around the captcha, otherwise your script won't see the content and thus cannot grab it.

```
    Oh No!
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
    <title>Yellow Pages® | Data Protection</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico?v=2" rel="shortcut icon"/>
    <!--[if (lt IE 9)&!(IEMobile)]><script src="/assets/ie/respond.sensis-9575467dfbc008e5b0d486dc4f481624.js" type="text/javascript" ></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if (lt IE 10)&!(IEMobile)]><script src="/assets/ie/custom-event-ie9.js" type="text/javascript"
></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if (lt IE 10)&!(IEMobile)]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/ie/gradient-hacks-ie89-12453d23f1fec3d9d46e56cc6e023576.css"/><![endif]-->
    <script async="" defer="" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?"></script>
    <meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"/>
    </head>
    <body id="" style="border-width: 0;
                    background-color: #EDEDED;
                    font-size: 85%;
                    line-height: 1.3;
                    margin: 0;
                    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="padding: 10px 15px;
                        height: 70px;
                        min-height: 45px;
                        background-color: #ffce00;
                        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffce00, #fedb55, #ffce00);
                        box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 7px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);">
    <div style="position: relative;
                            max-width: 1240px;
                            margin: 0 auto;">
    <a href="/">
    <img alt="Yellow Pages" src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="width: 70px;"/>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <div style="margin-left: auto;
                            margin-right: auto;
                            max-width: 600px;
                            vertical-align: top;">
    <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF;
                                border-radius: 8px;
                                padding: 1px 10px;">
    <h1 style="font-weight: normal;">We have detected unusual traffic activity originating from your IP address.</h1>
    <div style="border-bottom: 1px #E7E7E7 solid;
                                    margin-top: 20px;
                                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                                    height: 1px;
                                    width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: auto;
                                    margin-right: auto;
                                    font-size: 20px;
                                    max-width: 460px;
                                    text-align: center;">
                            We value the quality of content provided to our customers, and to maintain this, we would like to ensure real humans are accessing our information.</div>
    <div style="margin-left: auto;
                                    margin-right: auto;
                                    margin-top: 30px;
                                    max-width: 305px;">
    <form action="/dataprotection" method="post" name="captcha" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; word-wrap: break-word; display: block;">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeukxwTAAAAANIgmFm7-cOKIY4avRNHiDB9xAD8"></div>
    <noscript>
    <div style="width: 302px; height: 352px;">
    <div style="width: 302px; height: 352px; position: relative;">
    <div style="width: 302px; height: 352px; position: absolute;">
    <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6LeukxwTAAAAANIgmFm7-cOKIY4avRNHiDB9xAD8" style="width: 302px; height:352px; border-style: none;">
    </iframe>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 250px; height: 80px; position: absolute; border-style: none;
            bottom: 21px; left: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; right: 25px;">
    <textarea class="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
            margin: 0px; padding: 0px; resize: none;" value="">
            </textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </noscript>
    <input name="path" type="hidden" value="/sa/gawler/mega-health-gawler-14366108-listing.html"/>
    <div style="margin-left: auto;
                                            margin-right: auto;
                                            text-align: center;
                                            padding: 15px 0;
                                            max-width: 260px;
                                            margin-top: 30px;">
    <button class="submit" style="width: 100%;
                                                    color: black;
                                                    padding: 10px 25px;
                                                    border-radius: 25px;
                                                    cursor: pointer;
                                                    border: none;
                                                    position: relative;
                                                    background-color: #ffce00;
                                                    display: inline-block;
                                                    text-align: center;
                                                    box-sizing: border-box;">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div style="border-bottom: 1px #E7E7E7 solid;
                                    margin-top: 20px;
                                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                                    height: 1px;
                                    width: 100%;"></div>
    <p style="font-weight: bold;">Why did this happen?</p>
    <p style="margin-top: 20px;">This page appears when online data protection services detect requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of our website's terms of use.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> We have detected unusual traffic activity originating from your IP
>   address.  We value the quality of content provided to our customers,
>   and to maintain this, we would like to ensure real humans are
>   accessing our information.

I guess the ethical thing would be to work together with the webpage administrator, or at least ask for permission.

Answer (score 0):

it protected by captcha, open with normal browser, verify captcha and set python requests with this user-agent and cookies. example code

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
    s.cookies.update({'JSESSIONID' : '3F7613186E3AF8C8086B025CC84FBE6B', 'yellow-guid' : '0c2f9764-5c3f-480b-877f-70dd0911de72'})
    response = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    name = soup.select_one("h1.listing-name")
    print(name)
```